# math.js derivative работает не правильно

Tags: javascript, математика, нейронные-сети

Я делаю простую нейросеть, и для нее мне нужна функция активации и ее производная.

Есть два поля ввода: f(x) и f'(x)

Пользователь вводит f(x), например: 1/(1 + exp(-x)). Программа автоматически вставляет в f'(x) результат данного кода:

```
math.string(math.derivative(here is our f(x), 'x'))
```

Я получаю это:

> exp(-x) / (exp(-x) + 1) ^ 2

Но ожидаю это:

> x*(1-x)

И моя нейросеть не обучается.

Она работает идеально с x*(1-x), поэтому я думаю что проблема в производной которую генерирует math.js derivative. Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка все же была в моем коде.

Я должен был *активировать* значение нейрона непосредственно перед использованием: `f(neurone.value)*connection` но вместо этого сохранял в значении нейрона на самом деле значение пропущенное через функцию активации: `neurone.value = f(neurone.value)` и потом `neurone.value*connection`

Итог: `x*(1 - x)` на самом деле был `f(x)*(1 - f(x))`